# Is it possible to remove the Partition filter=Required setting from BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have existed table with setting of  `Partition filter=Required`
I want to disable it so I can run queries on the table without having to specify the partition column in the `WHERE`.

Is it possible or must I create a new table and copy data to it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it possible or must I create a new table and copy data to it?

Yes, You can use an [ALTER command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_set_options_statement) to alter your table as follow:

```sql
#standardSQL
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS mydataset.newtable
SET OPTIONS(
    require_partition_filter = false
)
```

You can change the `require_partition_filter` back to true if needed using the same command

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't do it with ALTER TABLE, but in the cloud shell, this [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#bq_1) worked for me:

```
bq update --require_partition_filter=FALSE your_project_id:dataset.table_name
```