# BigQuery: How to set `require_partition_filter` by TableReference

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am going to set [require_partition_filter](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.require_partition_filter) to True on bigquery [Table](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/table.html). But I can access only [TableReference](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableReference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.TableReference) instead of Table. How to do this?

**UPDATE**

Maybe I did not express my question clearly. I need to write **python program** to do this. I would not like to set the configuration by commands or sql, because there are too many tables. In this program, I can generate TableReference `table_ref` in the following program. But how to set `require_parition_filter` on `table_ref`?

```
    def table(client, dataset_name, table_name):
        dataset = client.dataset(dataset_name)
        table_ref = dataset.table(table_name)
        return table_ref

    job = client.load_table_from_uri(
        glob, # google cloud storage bucket
        table_ref, # returned by table() function above
        job_id='123',
        job_config=config, # at beginning, set `require_parition_filter` here, but this deprecated
   )
```

Comment: You can use the `alter` command. See this answer as a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55688443/1031958

Comment: @Tamir please post it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: instead of posting duplicate - I would rather suggest marking this question as duplicate - you can do it by choosing close and then selecting "duplicate of" ... - of course if you fill it is a duplicate - which I am not sure

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I did not express my question clearly maybe. I need to do it in Python program. I would not like to set it by commands.

Comment: that is exactly what I thought when read your question along with tags. I had the "problem" with provided answer and tried to express this in my comment

Answer (score 2):

> How to do this?

As mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/55688443/1031958) you can use an [ALTER command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_set_options_statement) to alter your table as follow:

```sql
#standardSQL
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS mydataset.newtable
SET OPTIONS(
    require_partition_filter = false
)
```

You can change the `require_partition_filter` back to true if needed using the same command

Answer (score 0):

Note that the preferred way would be to get a `bigquery.Table` object from `TableReference`, change `require_partition_filter` and patch the table (similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59434504/6121516) with expiration date). However, as you mention that you can only access `TableReference`, you can also set 
`TimePartitioning.require_partition_filter` ([deprecated](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.table.TimePartitioning.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.TimePartitioning) according to docs) when creating the table with a load job. For example:

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("foo", "STRING"),
    ],
    time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        require_partition_filter = True
    )    
)
```

and it works as expected:

```sh
$ bq query "SELECT * FROM test.require_filter"
Waiting on JOB_ID ... (0s) Current status: DONE   
Error in query string: Error processing job 'JOB_ID': Cannot query over table 'test.require_filter' without a filter over column(s) '_PARTITION_LOAD_TIME',
'_PARTITIONDATE', '_PARTITIONTIME' that can be used for partition elimination
```

Full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery


PROJECT = "PROJECT_ID"
DATASET = "test"
TABLE = "require_filter"


def table(client, dataset_name, table_name):
    dataset = client.dataset(dataset_name)
    table_ref = dataset.table(table_name)
    return table_ref


client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT)

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    schema = [
        bigquery.SchemaField("foo", "STRING"),
    ],
    time_partitioning = bigquery.TimePartitioning(
        type_=bigquery.TimePartitioningType.DAY,
        require_partition_filter = True
    )    
)

data = {"foo": ["bar"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

table_ref = table(client, DATASET, TABLE)

load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
    df, 
    table_ref,
    job_config = job_config
)

result = load_job.result()
```