# Is it still possible to remove the Partition filter=Required setting from a BigQuery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to remove the requirement to filter over the partition column in a BigQuery partitioned table. [The answer presented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55688114/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-partition-filter-required-setting-from-bigquery-tab) does not seem to work: the query runs, shows the result

`"This statement altered the table named project:dataset.table"`

There is even a button to go to the table, but it still requires a partition filter.

**EDIT**: Including table configurations and the query used

```
Data location: US 
Table type: Partitioned 
Partitioned by: Day 
Partitioned on field: date 
Partition filter :Required
Clustered by: column_name1, column_name2, column_name3
```

I tried both the query exactly as provided in the answer:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS dataset.table
SET OPTIONS(
    require_partition_filter = false
)
```

and also

```
ALTER TABLE dataset.table
SET OPTIONS(
    require_partition_filter = false
)
```

For the second one, for example, i have the following information in my query history:

Query succeeded

```
Query completed in 0.159 sec
Job ID: job_id 
User: user
Location: United States (US)
Creation time: creation_time
Start time: start_time
End time: end_time
Duration: 0.2 sec 
Bytes processed: 0 B 
Bytes billed :0 B 
Job priority: INTERACTIVE 
Destination table: project:dataset.table
Write preference:
Use legacy SQL: false
```

"project", "dataset", "table", "job_id","user", "creation_time", "start_time", "end_time" have been replaced

Any help?

Comment: Can you share the table's configuration, the exact statement you used and the logs for it?

Comment: Although, the _ALTER_ command should work if you set the require_partition_filter to false. You can use the following command, as an alternative, ` bq update --norequire_partition_filter --time_partitioning_field=your_partition_field  project:dataset.table`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to further contribute to the community, this answer is based in my last comment.

While the ***ALTER*** command should work, according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#console_15). There is another option to update a dataset, table, view or model, which is the  bq update command.

There are various of flags within this command, including ***require_partition_filter*** and  ***norequire_partition_filter***, in order to set the partition filter to True or False, respectively. In your case you can use this command as follows:

```
bq update --norequire_partition_filter --time_partitioning_field=your_partition_field project:dataset.table
```

After submitting the command, you should receive the following message:

```
Table 'project_id_dataset_table_name' successfully updated.
```

Therefore, your table won't require a filter on the partitioning column any more.